# How do I cycle through tables in HTML

Tags: html

I have two tables - players who are registered and players who are not registered.  Each table has a different set of data that is associated with them. I would like to have it so that only one table is showing on the page and have an arrow button to hide the table that is currently showing and show the other table.

How may this be accomplished?

Comment: You could use jQuery and hide()/show() or toggle()

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show/hide tables with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420320/show-hide-tables-with-jquery)

Comment: you need to learn how to use javascript, unless you have a server side laguage that you can use.  Plain html won't do it unless you have two pages with the exact same content but one with the first table and the other with the second

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Pete stated, plain html won't do it, so you'll need a bit of JavaScript, and jQuery is a very popular and powerfull library (written in JavaScript) to accomplish these things with just a few lines of code.

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/UFEN2/) of how to implement such a thing:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#changeTable").click(function () {
        $("#registred").toggle();
        $("#not-registred").toggle();
    });
});
```

*NOTE: you have to include a `<script>` tag linking to jQuery, and one of the divs containing the tables should be hidden from start by a style `display: none` (as in the example)*

So the final result will be something like:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myStyles.css"/>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="changeTable" type=button value="Show The Other Table"/>
    <div id="registred" />
    <div id="not-registred" style="display: none;" />
    <!-- rest of your HTML code -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
             $("#changeTable").click(function () {
                 $("#registred").toggle();
                 $("#not-registred").toggle();
              });
         });
    <script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should add note that one of them should have defined styles with `display: none` - because in other way both will be shown or hidden after toggle.

Comment: Good point, it's in the fiddle, but it doesn't hurt to point it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Set display: none; for both (or just one if there is a default) tables in your CSS. Make a Javascript function that will detect which one has a display of none, and toggle it to inline. Something like:

```
function toggleVisibility(){
  if(Document.getElementById("Table1").style.display == "none"){
    Document.getElementById("Table1").style.display = "inline";
    Document.getElementById("Table2").style.display = "none";
  }else{
    Document.getElementById("Table2").style.display = "inline";
    Document.getElementById("Table1").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

And then just call this function from your toggle button and you're good to go.

Comment: A better approach in this case will be classes not styles... Or styles cached in variables - it will be less resources eating and less DOM hitting...